# Notification email on Content creation - admin approval?

Tags: 7, notifications

I made a custom content type to replace comments, as the current comment options are not satisfactory for me. Anonymous users can create this content type (comment).

I need to send an email to the administrator users each time a new comment is written, to allow them to publish the new comments.

I searched for notification email, but it is not what I expected; it only allows to send emails on regular basis. Maybe I could not make it work.

How can I send automatic emails to administrators to notify them a new comment has been created, and it is waiting for approval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try the [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) modules, it can does exactly what you want.

> The rules module allows site administrators to define conditionally executed actions based on occurring events (known as reactive or ECA rules). It's a replacement with more features for the trigger module in core and the successor of the Drupal 5 workflow-ng module.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be the [Subscriptions](http://drupal.org/project/subscriptions) module.

> This module enables users to subscribe to be notified of changes to nodes or taxonomies, such as new comments in specific forums, or additions to some category of blog. Once enabled, all nodes will have an additional link that allows the user to change their subscriptions. Users have tab on their user screen to manage their own subscriptions. Users can also set an auto subscribe function which notifies the user if anyone comments on posts they have made. Admins can set this on by default.